# How to match the following coordinates pattern using regex on C++?

Tags: c++, regex, string, coordinates

I'd like to check if it match the following format:

(integer,integer), including the parenthesis and the commas. For example:for (3,4) would return true and for (6.4 would return false
I tried with

```
string input;
regex check("(\\-|+)?[[:d:]]+,?(\\-|+)?[[:d:]]+");
cin >> input;
if (regex_match(input, check)) cout << "okay" << endl;
else cout << "error";
```

but I'm getting runtime error

Comment: `(\\-|+)?` => `(-|\\+)?`. Please provide an example input that you need to match and some examples you do not want to match.

Comment: Or more simply `[-+]?`.

Comment: Try `regex check(R"(\([-+]?\d+,[-+]?\d+\))")`. Note that `regex_match` matches the whole string, it does not return true for partial matches.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - You should post that as an answer

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew for example, (1,2) should return true, (-3,4) should return true, (4,7 should return false, gggggg should return false. It just has to be parenthesis integer comma integer parenthesis

Comment: @Marelisse - `(` and `)` are tokens in regular expressions; they're used as grouping operators. If you want to match a literal `(`, your regex needs to contain `\(`. In order to encode those characters in C++, you can use the literal string syntax `R"\("` or you can use escapes as you've used previously.

Comment: thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for

```
regex check(R"(\([-+]?\d+,[-+]?\d+\))")
```

This defines a pattern like `^\([-+]?\d+,[-+]?\d+\)$` when used with `std::regex_match` that requires a full string match.

Details:

- `^` - start of string (implicit in `regex_match`)
- `\(` - a `(`
- `[-+]?` - 1 or 0 `+` or `-` chars
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `,` - a comma
- `[-+]?` - 1 or 0 `+` or `-` chars
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `\)` - a `)`
- `$` - end of string (implicit in `regex_match`)

[C++ demo](https://ideone.com/d7pye5):

```
regex check(R"(\([-+]?\d+,[-+]?\d+\))");
string s1("(44,45)");
string s2("(44,45");
smatch match;
if (regex_match(s1, match, check)) {
        cout << s1 << ": Matched!" << endl; 
} else {
    cout << s1 << ": Not matched!" << endl; 
}
if (regex_match(s2, match, check)) {
        cout << s2 << ": Matched!" << endl;     
} else {
    cout << s2 << ": Not matched!" << endl; 
}
```

Output:

```
(44,45): Matched!
(44,45: Not matched!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try input this regex `\(\d{1,},\d{1,}\)`

Maybe it might works

Comment: Does not handle input in the form: "(-1234, 5678)", nor does it escape the parenthesis. Also, you can just use `\d+` instead of `\d{1,}`.

Comment: @antiduh -- that's a harsh downvote, given the the **problem statement** doesn't mention minus signs. That's a helpful comment, but you have to give him a chance to act on it.

Comment: @PeteBecker - It doesn't solve the problem, thus downvote. Reading between the lines, its fairly easy to see that the asker is looking for optional sign characters due to their inclusion in the attempt: `(\\-|+)?`. We ask posters to give us what they've tried for a reason. His original post, at the time I commented and voted, also didn't properly handle parens. It still doesn't solve the problem, thus I haven't changed my position.

Comment: @antiduh - utterly missing the point. Reread what I said in my previous comment, and **read to the end**. Instant downvoting is harsh, and discouraging to newcomers. Remember, you were one once, and in other contexts, will be again.

Comment: @PeteBecker - "Why is voting important?" from the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote "Voting is important so that good content rises to the top and incorrect content falls to the bottom.". I'm following the suggested rules of the community. If he deletes his incorrect post, he'll get his rep back. If he makes an edit that fixes the problems with the post, I'll rescind my downvote. Until then, incorrect content falls to the bottom.

Comment: @antiduh - sigh. The help center doesn't say "downvote immediately if there are problems with an answer". That's a **harsh** interpretation. Besides, the edits you're looking for **have already been made**, but at the moment you haven't undone your downvote.

Comment: @PeteBecker - No, the edits have not been made. He's still missing some sort of handling for `-` or `+` characters. See my first comment.